# Drop Down List doesn't locked

Tags: javascript, select, data-binding

I have a div with drop down list. 
I tried to disable all div. I succeeded but I can't disable the dropdown list.
This div is consist of select tag called cb3.  I working with Knock Out.(All the data binding you see).
the condition value: hete.selectedvalue,enable:format.selectedvalue()!='xxx' destroy the disable I would like to make.

```
<div class="DivStyle1" data-bind="disableByRole: hetel.readOnlyValue">
        <div id="div-for-cb3" class="div-for-combo poscombo3"">
<select id="cb3" onchange="onSelectChange(this.id, this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)" dir="rtl" class="SelectStyle3" data-bind="options: hete.defaultValue,value: hete.selectedvalue,enable:format.selectedvalue()!='xxx' "><option value="x1">x1</option><option value="x2">x2</option><option value="x3">x3</option><option value="x4">x4</option></select>
            <span id="label-for-cb3" class="label-for-combo" data-bind="text:hete.selectedvalue"">x4</span>
        </div>

        <span class="SpanStyle3">:hete</span>
        <img id="hetelIMG" onclick="ChangeImg('hete','#heteIMG')" data-bind="attr:{src: myview.hete.readOnlyUrl}" class="ImgStyle3" " src="./idle.png">
    </div>
```

in other js file:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disableByRole = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        var isDisabled = valueUnwrapped == 'true' 
        if (isDisabled)
        $(element).find('*').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                            .prop('onclick', false)
                            .css('opacity',0.7);
    }
};
```

Only the select tag isn't disabled... why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add this .change() after .

```
 $(element).find('*').attr('disabled', 'disabled').prop('onclick', false).css('opacity',0.7).change();
```

Comment: I did it. It's disabled the select tag, but unfortunately now the images are ruined - empty image - only square without a image....

Comment: probably due to the parent div's attribute data-bind=disabled by role, Take this out. Then create another child div within this outer div that does not contain the image element and put that there